# Disappearing R markdown image captions

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc

I have an Rmarkdown with an html output.

The following code works well - it places two images side by side perfectly.  But is there a reason why the following code does not print the specified captions under the pictures themselves?  I have followed the formula exactly - why does the text inside brackets `[]` not show up as captions?

```
    ![Caption for the picture.](cropped1.png){#id .class width=50% height=50%}![Caption for the picture.](cropped2.png){#id .class width=50% height=50%}
```

The following are the document configs:

```
output:
  html_document:
    theme: "flatly"
    toc: true
    fig_caption: yes
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
      smooth_scroll: true
```

Comment: I guess there is a ```fig.cap``` function for captions from ```knitr```. Otherwise, I could understand your problem wrong.

Comment: This is for inline text, not in code blocks