# R Markdown image caption not showing

Tags: r, r-markdown

In R Markdown, I am trying to add a caption to an image, but it is not showing. Using RStudio and "Knit to HTML" Code & screenshot of HTML are below. There is no caption, even though it is in the brackets.

```
# First test
## SubHeader 1
kl;jdafkjjdsfajk;
![literally the most amazing apple ever](C:/Users/.../Stemilt-Cosmic-Crisp-Apple-2019.jpg)
```

[image]

[This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473039/disappearing-r-markdown-image-captions) is unanswered, but it looks like "fig.cap" is needed. I tried adding `{r fig.cap = "caption2- literally the most amazing apple ever"}` to the code (as line 5 in the above) but it did not work, it just printed the exact text that was entered, curly braces and all.

Comment: I thought the issue was that there is no image text, because in your example output, the image text is missing. You should fix that and make the question a little more clear.

Comment: I want a caption, like in the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31926623/figures-captions-and-labels-in-knitr). What else should I say instead of "I want a caption"? There is no problem just writing text, as "kl;jdafkjjdsfajk;" prints fine.

Comment: I think the combination of "it did not work" and the missing image text (which is still missing by the way) gives the impression that no image text was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use the `fig.cap` argument to an R code chunk with `knitr::include_graphics`, or provide a caption through a markdown image link.

A minimal example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

# Option 1: `fig.cap` with `include_graphics`

```{r echo=FALSE, fig.cap = "Figure caption"}
knitr::include_graphics("https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/rabbduck.jpg")
```


# Option 2: The markdown way way

![Figure caption](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/gifs/rabbduck.jpg)
````

produces

[image]

Comment: Just to note that option 2 (which is the same method as used in the original question) **does** generate a caption - if you examine the HTML you'll find a paragraph of class = caption. Perhaps the OP was confused because it is not styled in the same way as a caption generated when graphics are generated in a code chunk _i.e._ centered and italicised. [Same goes for](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp)`<figcaption>`.

Comment: Option 2 was in my OP and didn't work, hence the question

Answer (score 2):

maybe I over thought this, but I saw with HTML output docs, you need the `fig_caption: true` in your YAML for the the figure to get rendered with a caption. I used a few packages I use when posting images in R markdown reports.

````
---
title: "test"
output: 
  html_document:
      fig_caption: true
---
    
```{r setup, fig.cap="This is a screenshot",fig.align = 'center', warning=FALSE,     message=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(magick)
ggdraw() +
  draw_image("delete.png") 
```
````

[image]

Comment: This is not necessary. [`fig_caption = TRUE` by default for `html_document`](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/898199b9bc3df2da50edd1f7ded472e6c9e46c1b/R/html_document.R#L224).